# How to Properly Sanitize NestJS Input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I’m asking this as I can’t seem to get a straight answer.

So, NestJS has a very elegant way of handling validation by using decorators. That is, you define DTO classes with properties you expect, and annotate them with class-validator decorators. For example, assume we have a route that accepts input from a contact form.

```
class ContactInfoDTO {
     @IsString()
     @IsNotEmpty()
     name: string
     
     @IsEmail()
     email: string
     
     @IsString()
     @IsNotEmpty
     subject: string

     @IsString()
     @IsNotEmpty()
     body: string

}
```

This works great for validation. If I enter an invalid email, it will reject it as expected. But, here’s my question. What about input Sanitization? Say, for example, I enter a some JavaScript in the body parameter? Like, say, my body looks like this:

```
body: “Hello <script>//some malicious code here</script>”
```

Now, this is still accepted. Even though the script tags are not converted to HTML entities, which does pose a bit of a security risk.

So, my question is does NestJS have any kind of built-in Sanitization mechanisms? Is there proper documentation on this? Because I can’t really find any, despite this kind of thing being very important in the context of web development.

What’s the best practice for doing input Sanitization in NestJS?

Answer (score 10):

Use `sanitize-html` with `Transform` like this:

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsString } from 'class-validator';
import * as sanitizeHtml from 'sanitize-html';

export class ContactInfoDTO {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsString()
  @Transform((params: TransformFnParams) => sanitizeHtml(params.value))
  public body: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Reza response this is an up to date version (cannot put in comment due to reputation)

```
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsString } from 'class-validator';
import * as sanitizeHtml from 'sanitize-html';

// ...

@Transform((params: TransformFnParams) => sanitizeHtml(params.value))
field: string
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the class-sanitizer [library](https://github.com/typestack/class-sanitizer) and apply its decorators to your model's properties:

```
class ContactInfoDTO {
     @IsString()
     @IsNotEmpty()
     name: string
     
     @IsEmail()
     email: string
     
     @IsString()
     @IsNotEmpty
     subject: string

     @IsString()
     @IsNotEmpty()
     @Escape()
     body: string

}
```

Comment: Okay. Although, on its repository it says its depreciated and to use class-validate and class-transformer instead. Is there no way to do Sanitization with class-validate and class-transformer?

Comment: sure you can just create custom sanitizations as custom decorators if those are not present